# Cypress - network request with partial url

Tags: api, cypress

Im testing some API and i want to use only part of the URL.
Some of the URL params are are unexpected so when im using `request` i want to ignore some params.
Here is an example:

```
cy.request(getApi(https://api.example.com/api/geo_insights/impressions?alt_source=true&lat=40.7129032&lng=-74.0063033&targeting_radius=2500))
```

I want to use only the value of `targeting_radius` param and ignore the values of the rest of the params, like : `https://api.example.com/api/geo_insights/impressions?alt_source=true&lat=**&lng=**&targeting_radius=2500`.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Run some string splitting on the URL

```js
const url = `https://api.example.com/api/geo_insights/impressions?alt_source=true&lat=40.7129032&lng=-74.0063033&targeting_radius=2500`

const urlBaseAndParams = url.split('?')
const paramSection = urlBaseAndParams[1].split('&')
const params = paramSection.split('&')
const lastParam = params[params.length-1]

const requestUrl = `${urlBaseAndParams[0]}?${lastParam}`
```

You can merge some of those steps, I just break it down for clarity.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear, i also need to call the rest of the params but i dont know what the values are.
Is there a way to call the params without the values?

Comment: I see - that would depend on the API, if it can accept such params. My hunch is no, but you tell me does work with `&lat=**&lng=**`?